# Can not create a Hadoop Eclipse server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, ant

I have hadoop 2.2.0 installed my Linux 12.1 
I successfully created a hadoop plugin jar file and copied into the eclipse plugin folder using [this](https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin) plugin . When I try to create a dfs server in eclipse I have following error. I tried with different guava releases but I still have same error.

Anyone could help me about this issue?

Thank you.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Interners
at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringInterner.(StringInterner.java:48)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2108)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2001)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1918)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:721)
at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.server.HadoopServer.addPluginConfigDefaultProperties(HadoopServer.java:450)
at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.server.HadoopServer.(HadoopServer.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.servers.HadoopLocationWizard.(HadoopLocationWizard.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.actions.NewLocationAction$1.(NewLocationAction.java:41)
at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.actions.NewLocationAction.run(NewLocationAction.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:588)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:456)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4421)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3771)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3391)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1122)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:146)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:565)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:80)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:372)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:226)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Interners cannot be found by osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.hadoop.eclipse"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.18.0"; singleton:="true"
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:411)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:331)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:323)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem! The problem was in manifest file that located in the jar file had wrong location of guava.jar. I was building plugin with the "ant" that supposed to write the location like this "lib/guava-15.0.jar" instead "lib/guava-{$guava.version}".

Answer (score 1):

The link to the plugin you're using is missing. So all I can do is diagnose the symptoms:

The relevent part of the stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Interners cannot be found 
by osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.hadoop.eclipse"; type="osgi.bundle";
version:Version="0.18.0"; singleton:="true"
```

So there is a missing jar on your classpath. Maven Central has a list of jars containing this class:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22com.google.common.collect.Interners%22

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MarkO'Conner. I updated the plugin link in the question part. I checked that missing jar which is guava, but it is already exist in the lib folder. I tried different versions of that guava.jar but result didn't changed.

Comment: Hey @Mark I've got the solution. You were right jar file supposed to missing base on the stack trace but it had wrong path in the manifest file...